# Оптимизация работы запроса

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, запрос, инспекция-кода

Как можно оптимизировать??? т е берется во внимание как запрос (таблица, бд) так и сам сервер). Записей 17 млн. минимум. Т к по результату запроса строится график - то он не самый лучший. Прошу помощи.

Запрос в принципе не сложный:

```
SELECT "Extent1"."shop_id", 
"Extent1"."receipt_number", 
"Extent1"."kassa_number", 
"Extent1"."datetime_close", 
"Extent1"."z_number", 
"Extent1"."receipt_type", 
"Extent1"."datetime_open", 
"Extent1"."discount_sum", 
"Extent1"."receipt_return_number", 
"Extent1"."discount_info", 
"Extent1"."user_info", 
"Extent1"."system_info",
"Extent1"."kassir_id", 
"Extent1"."summa", 
"Extent1"."card_info", 
"Extent1"."receipt_return_kassa_number" 
FROM "public"."t_receipts" AS "Extent1" 
WHERE "Extent1"."datetime_close" >= 1551444799 AND "Extent1"."datetime_close" <= 1564444799
```

Сама таблица:

```
-- Table: t_receipts

-- DROP TABLE t_receipts;

CREATE TABLE t_receipts
(
  kassa_number integer NOT NULL, 
  z_number integer NOT NULL, 
  receipt_type integer NOT NULL, 
  datetime_open integer NOT NULL, -- время открытия чека (unix time)
  datetime_close integer NOT NULL, -- время закрытия чека (unix time)
  discount_sum numeric(12,2) NOT NULL, 
  receipt_return_number integer,
  replicstatus integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  shop_id character varying(32) NOT NULL,
  receipt_number integer NOT NULL,
  discount_info character varying, 
  user_info character varying, 
  system_info character varying, 
  kassir_id integer NOT NULL, 
  summa numeric(12,2) NOT NULL, 
  card_info character varying,
  receipt_return_kassa_number integer
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE t_receipts
  OWNER TO psp;
COMMENT ON TABLE t_receipts
  IS 'таблица чеков';

-- Index: ind_d_t_close

-- DROP INDEX ind_d_t_close;

CREATE INDEX ind_d_t_close
  ON t_receipts
  USING btree
  (datetime_close);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

C track_io_timing
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *"строится график - то он не самый лучший. Прошу помощи."* - уточните в чем именно вы просите помощи, улучшить время выполнения запроса или сгладить график, или что-то еще?

Comment: если вопрос о производительности - покажите `explain (analyze,buffers)`. Желательно с включенным `track_io_timing`. Ну и классический контрвопрос - как вы собираетесь показывать на графике 17млн точек.

Comment: @Мелкий это предварительный запрос, сформерованный `EF`. В который передаются параметры даты (как видно в самом запросе). Показываю так - выбираю даты (от - до) потом группирую по ней и считаю сумму и количество чеков.

Comment: @Мелкий добавил

Comment: @Kromster вопрос во времени...т е оптимизации

Comment: *потом группирую по ней и считаю сумму и количество чеков* Где именно? на клиенте, что ли?

Comment: @Akina средствами языка на back

Comment: Ну так небось 38 секунд - это время. которое уходит на выгрузку набора данных на клиента. Считайте всё прямо в запросе, и получайте уже готовые к графическому представлению компактные данные.

Comment: `explain (analyze)` - это без учёта передачи данных. А track_io_timing наверное покажет, что большую часть времени как раз читали 127 тыс блоков с дисков. 3к iops в принципе не так плохо для однопоточной нагрузки.

Comment: @Мелкий добавил еще `track_io_timing`. Что можете посоветовать для увеличения производительнсти?

Comment: @Akina время выполнения 15 мин 38 сек,и при чем тут клиент и т п...я щас говорю за запрос, который непостредственно запускаю с тулзов pgAdmin

Comment: время выполнения запроса - 41 секунда, половина этого времени - io. А если вы результат видите спустя 15 минут - то эти 15 минут тратятся как раз на передачу по сети и обработку клиентом, а не базой. Базе потребовалось только 41 секунда.

Comment: @Мелкий я на локалке делаю...какому клиенту? `pgAdmin`у ?

Comment: да, а чем не клиент? У самой СУБД postgresql нет user interface. Протокол и тот бинарный, телнетом как по http1.x не пообщаться.

Comment: Можете посмотреть в сторону партицирование таблиц, если у вас слишком много данных. А если у вас данные не модифицируются то можно посмотреть в сторону БД которые умеют работать с большим набором данных

Comment: @ЕвгенийГаврилов а какие это БД? Вы еолоночные имеете в виду?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Да, что-то типа clickhouse, elasticsearch